# Internet Explorer border bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

On [this page](http://dev.realreads.co.uk/sciencefiction/titles/) in Internet Explorer 6 and 7  on XP and Vista there is a bug where scrolling the page seems to lose bits of the left and right borders. Has anyone seen this behaviour before, and does anyone have any ideas to avoid it?

**Edit:** This is fixed now. If anyone would like to see what the problem was, find the following line and disable it in Firebug:

```
zoom:1; /*for hasLayout*/
```

Comment: That's a weird bug; I've never seen it before.  It doesn't happen on IE8 on Windows 7, but it does in compatibility mode.

Comment: Try shrinking the width of the text are. I have seen it before, but not sure the resolution.

Comment: Or,...  we could all just boycott IE and use Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can often deal with this bug by applying position:relative to the elements in question. height:1% can also help. Another typical "black-magic" solution to dealing with IE6 and has to do with hasLayout. See http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html for more information.

If giving it hasLayout doesn't solve your particular issue, then you will definitely want to make sure that there is no contained element with a background of #fff that is expanding past the bounds of the containing element (likely due to IE6's way of handling padding and width).

Comment: `hasLayout` fixed it. `position:relative` fixed the particular problem but opened up a whole new can of worms. `zoom:1` from satzansatz.de sorted it. It's nice to have an inert way of dealing with the issue. It may mean that my CSS doesn't validate, but at the moment I really don't give a toss.